# How to get all value that provide by checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get all value from chekboxes that provided ?

THis is the code :

```
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function(data){

  var checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='selection[]']");

  for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
      console.log(checkbox[i]); // get html string
      console.log(checkbox[i].val()); // checkbox[i].val is not a function
  }

});
```

Please advise.

Comment: Try `(checkbox[i]).val()` instead

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I was looking at his code verbatim - that's a good catch and possibly another bug that needs to be fixed by using `i` rather than `1`

Comment: Use https://api.jquery.com/each/ instead of a for loop, and `$(this).val()` inside of it ...

Comment: checkbox[i].val() // is not a function . Please see my update question

Answer (score 2):

You want all chekbox values? Try this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").serialize()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `checkbox[i].value` to be able to get the values of the checkboxes

```js
$(document).ready(function(data) {
  var checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='selection[]']");
  for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    console.log(checkbox[i].value); // checkbox[i].val is not a function
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="4" />
```

Comment: Perhaps, it would be better to just use `checkbox.eq(i).val()` inside `for`? No need to wrap to jQuery objects again.